# Why can't my friend see a photo on my timeline that is supposed to viewable by friends of anyone tagged?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags, facebook-privacy

I was recently tagged in a photo.  The person that took it is not my friend (a mutual friend of ours, who also appears in the photo, tagged me).  I approved it to appear on my timeline.  If I look at my own profile, I see it.

The privacy settings say that it should be viewable by friends of anyone tagged, thus I would think that my friends should be able to view it:

[image]

However, when I view my profile, use the "view as" feature and select one of my friends, it's not on my timeline (implying that they cannot see it).

Why?  Is this because of:

- some privacy setting that I have configured?
- a bug in facebook's settings (the screenshot above says that friends of anyone tagged can see it but they really can't)?
- a bug in the "view as" feature (i.e. they actually can see it)?
- something else?

Comment: Can't say for sure so I don't want to answer officially, but I would guess it's a bug in the "view as" feature.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem and solved it with the following change in my privacy settings.

Go to "Timeline and Tagging Settings" and Check out the Option "When you're tagged in a post, who do you want to add the audience if they aren't already in it?"

It was set to "only me" and I changed it to "friends" and now friends can see post I've been tagged in.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but I've noticed that this doesn't happen when viewing as the mutual friend, who is also tagged in the photo.

It also doesn't happen when viewing as another person who is not friends with whoever uploaded the photo, but is friends with me and the other person tagged in the photo.

The problem doesn't seem to happen when whoever uploaded the photo shared it with friends of friends.

Answer (score 1):

My profile was having the same problem for a while. I figured out what worked for me. Go to settings, then click timeline and tagging. In the 'who can see things on my timeline' section I had to change those answers to 'friends'. I'm not sure why that affected the visibility of my tagged 'photos of me'album but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Facebook has been undergoing large changes and thus many bugs have come about. The most likely reason seems to me that it is a bug in the Facebook system, but it could be one of two:

1. That the 'View as' feature is bugged, as you and @josmh suggested, or
2. That the privacy settings are bugged, and your friends really can't see it

The former of the two is far more likely, but I believe these are the two possible answers.

Oh also, it could be down to your account settings - have you inadvertently set all timeline images to only be visible to you, or something of the kind?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Facebook has been undergoing large
changes and thus many bugs have come
about. The most likely reason seems to me
that it is a bug in the Facebook system, but it
could be one of two:
1. That the 'View as' feature is bugged, as
you and @josmh suggested, or
2. That the privacy settings are bugged,
and your friends really can't see it
The former of the two is far more likely, but I
believe these are the two possible answers.
Oh also, it could be down to your account
settings - have you inadvertently set all
timeline images to only be visible to you, or
something of the kind?